# Vine like video play in UITableviewCell and download and store it to cache

Tags: iphone, uitableview, video, download, vine

Hello I am trying to play multiple video in UITableView from server I have done with playing on UITableViewCell which is displayed on Screen I have problem with download video like vine app when cell is visible and play it on cell.

Does anybody face same issue before then help would be appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check full visible  cell and play it after scroll did end

Comment: Yes I did it but I want to download before play it and store it to cache

Comment: when scoll did end put one by one download (only display cell video) if already downloaded no need to download , at the time of play check if it is available in catch then play from catch other wise play from live URL..

Comment: Yes I am playing from live URL but what I want when user scroll down particular cell then if that video is not downloaded then download first and then play it to that particular cell. If you have any suggested sdk or sample app it would be grate

Comment: dont wait from download completion for video download it to background and play from Live URL

Comment: I need same as vine app